# PUT request access blocked

Tags: javascript, kotlin, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, netty

I have been trying to update values in a certain table with a PUT request. However, I keep getting those errors and I am not sure why:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/ping/1001 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/ping/1001' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Whenever I switch the request to a GET request it works.

My backend

```
 embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {

       routing {
            get("/api/ping/{num?}"){
                var nsq_num: Int = Integer.valueOf(call.parameters["num"]?: "1001")
                var stmt: Statement? = null
                var resultset: ResultSet? = null
                val obj = arrayListOf<SRTEntry>()
                        .....
                        .....
                val gson = Gson()
                var str = gson.toJson(obj)
                call.response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                call.respondText(str, ContentType.Application.Json)
            }
            put("/api/ping/{num?}"){
                var nsq_num: Int = Integer.valueOf(call.parameters["num"]?: "1001")
                var stmt: PreparedStatement? = null
                var resultset: ResultSet? = null
                val obj = arrayListOf<SRTEntry>()
                        .....
                        .....
                val gson = Gson()
                var str = gson.toJson(obj)
                call.response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                call.respondText(str, ContentType.Application.Json)
            }
```

Frontend that calls PUT request

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/ping/1001";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(event){
    if (parseInt(req.status, 10) != 200) {
        return;
    }
    var text = req.responseText;
    console.log(text);
}
req.open("PUT", url, true);
req.send();
```

Call to GET request:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/ping/1001";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(event){
    if (parseInt(req.status, 10) != 200) {
        return;
    }
    var text = req.responseText;
    console.log(text);
}
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send();
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is more to CORS than one response header. Make sure server is also handling OPTIONS requests

Comment: what @charlietfl said. Browsers will send a preflight options request to all url paths and you must respond with the correct headers. Also the reason your getting CORS is because web browsers consider different ports as different origins even though the request is to localhost.

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix it!  https://dev.to/effingkay/cors-preflighted-requests--options-method-3024 has good information about the problem!

Comment: @hm1233 request you to please mark the answer as closed. Prefer writing an answer to this and closing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
install(CORS){
            method(HttpMethod.Put)
            anyHost()
        }
```

Before routing fixed it for me as shown below:

```
install(CORS){
    method(HttpMethod.Put)
    anyHost()
}
routing {
   get("/api/ping/{num?}"){
   var nsq_num: Int = Integer.valueOf(call.parameters["num"]?: "1001")
   var stmt: Statement? = null
   var resultset: ResultSet? = null
   ...
```

You can get more information about it from https://dev.to/effingkay/cors-preflighted-requests--options-method-3024